# 301 Redirect all pages including query strings to main page of new domain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to 301 redirect all  urls, including urls with query strings, to one single page on a new domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.domain2.com/" [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that this does not strip querystrings from the URL.
It redirects

```
domain1.com/?PageAction=VIEWPROD&ProdID=57&HS=1
```

to

```
domain2.com/?PageAction=VIEWPROD&ProdID=57&HS=1
```

and not

```
domain2.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this rule for stripping query string from resulting URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Note `?` in the end of `http://www.domain2.com/?` to strip out any existing query string in the original URL.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)